# Perform SUM query in ADO.NET

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I am getting following error

> ;expected

I am trying to find sum of column values in my **webform**.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select SUM("AMOUNT DEPOSITED ") From MAIN_TABLE6";
    Double amount = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    Label3.Text = amount.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The error is obvious even from syntax coloring - you have one string ` "Select SUM("` followed by the C# tokens names AMOUNT and DEPOSITED. Use square brackets or escape the double quotes.

Comment: In any case, ASP.NET is a web stack. It doesn't query databases. What you used is ADO.NET. It's used in a very unsafe manner though - there's one global connection that's never used. All tutorials show creating the connection inside a `using` block to ensure it's closed as soon as possible, even in case of errors. Check [this tutorial from the docs for example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-simple-data-application-by-using-adonet?view=vs-2019#write-the-code-for-the-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update-voted the answer by @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ because he solved the problem with the brackets. However I like to see that database objects are closed and disposed. If database objects are kept local to the methods where they are used then `using` blocks accomplish this even if there is and error.

It is possible to pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection and pass the command text and connection to the constructor of the command. `CommandType.Text` is the default value so it is not necessary to set it.

I have opened the connection directly before the `.Execute...` and it is closed immediately after. The user interface is not updated until the connection is closed.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double amount;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select SUM([AMOUNT DEPOSITED]) From MAIN_TABLE6;", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            amount = (double)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        Label3.Text = amount.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use brackets to enclose your columns in **SQL Server**.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select SUM([AMOUNT DEPOSITED]) From MAIN_TABLE6";
    Double amount = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    Label3.Text = amount.ToString();    
}
```